# Returning a Class that Stores on Heap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory

I'm having a memory-related crash in my project. I managed to reduce it down to the following "toy" project:

```
class Foo {
public:

    Foo() : bar(nullptr) {
        bar = new int(3);
    }

    ~Foo() {
        if (bar) {
            delete bar;
            bar = nullptr;
        }
    }

private:
    int* bar;
};

Foo test() {
    Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main() {
    test();
             // <--- Crash!
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot figure out why I'm crashing at the line specified. This is what I've gathered so far, please do correct me if I'm wrong:

Basically, I'm creating `foo` on the stack in `test()`. `Foo` allocates some memory on the heap. All is well. Then I try to return `foo`. `foo` is returned, but it is immediately destroyed. Then, when exiting, I'm again trying to destroy `foo`; and hence I'm calling `Foo`'s destructor twice, and I crash. What I do not get is why this is a problem. I'm checking for `Foo::bar` being null before deleting it, and if I do delete it, I set it to null afterwards.

Why should this cause a crash? How can I "fix" this? What am I doing wrong? I'm so confused! :(

Update: The main reason for why this is happening is because of lack of a copy constructor, as stated in the answers below. However, my original project did have copy constructor, or so I thought. Turns out if your class is derived, you must explicitly create a copy constructor for the derived class. `Base(const Derived& other)` does not count as a copy constructor!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You violated the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

When you're manually managing memory inside your constructor and destructor, you MUST also provide a copy constructor and assignment operator, otherwise your program will double-delete and use memory after delete.

In your particular example, you have the compiler-provided copy constructor.  When `foo` is copied to the return value of `test`, you have two objects with the same `bar` pointer.  The local `foo` goes out of scope and is destroyed, then its `bar` is set to `nullptr`.  But the copy, the return value, still has a non-null pointer.  Then it is destroyed also, and deletes the same memory again.

Comment: Yup. This was it. And it wasn't because I didn't have a copy constructor. In my actual project, the class was derived from a base class. When I wrote it, I thought `Base(const Derived& other)` and `Base& operator=(const Derived& other)` would count as copy constructor and assignment operators respectively. Turns out they don't! And I learn something today! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a copy-constructor and, most likely, an assignment operator.

Really, though, your problem lies in manually managing memory. This is almost always a terrible idea, as it is one of the most common ways bugs creep into your code. Use `shared_ptr`s instead of manually managing memory in your code, and it is amazing how much easier your code is to maintain!